# How to change the line height in the menu

Tags: customize, css, gtk3

Here "menu" means something which appears when you hit F10. (Not the menubar.)

Because my display is small, several options are hidden below. (See the following image. You can not see "Quit".)

[image]

This is sometimes annoying me, so I would like to make the line hight in the menu list smaller. But the following `gtk.css` does not affect the line-height.

```
#pane #menubar GtkMenuShell 
{
    line-height: 100px !important;
    background-color: #000;
}
```

My question is : what should I write in `gtk.css` to change the line-height in the list of menu?

Comment: I am using emacs on openSUSE. I am currently working on KDE, but other gtk application such as gimp does not have this problem. (Namely the line-height is not large.)

Comment: +1. I don't think you can change it. I'd be interested to know how, if you can.

Comment: FWIW, an alternative way to use the keyboard to navigate menu-bar menus is to use library [La Carte](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/LaCarte). it lets you not only use keys to drill down into menus one item/submenu at a time; it also lets you got to menus/submenus directly, by matching their names (completion).